# YQL returns old data

Tags: yql

It happens starting from around 8 Apr, the data returned from YQL are old and different on each refresh. Here is my [YQL statement request](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fetav3.kmb.hk%2F%3Faction%3Dgeteta%26lang%3Dtc%26route%3D74K%26bound%3D1%26stop%3DHO04T10000%26stop_seq%3D22%26serviceType%3D2%22&format=json).

The statement is simply preventing CORS issues when fetching data from other sites

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from html where url="http://etav3.kmb.hk/?action=geteta&lang=tc&route=74K&bound=1&stop=HO04T10000&stop_seq=22&serviceType=2"&format=json
```

I realized it is YQL's problem because fetching the [original URL](http://etav3.kmb.hk/?action=geteta&lang=tc&route=74K&bound=1&stop=HO04T10000&stop_seq=22&serviceType=2) have no any issues.

```
http://etav3.kmb.hk/?action=geteta&lang=tc&route=74K&bound=1&stop=HO04T10000&stop_seq=22&serviceType=2
```

Some users have reported similar issue and reported the problem fixed:
[Yahoo weather API, randomly returns old data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703009/yahoo-weather-api-randomly-returns-old-data)

But I am still facing the problem right now. What could I do to fix it? Thanks for help.